# how to use LEFT JOIN in mysql

Tags: mysql

i am getting an error with my code and i would appreciate some help. this is just my first day trying to learn so please keep it as simple as possible thanks

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'FROM specials LEFT JOIN products_description LEFT JOIN products 
WHERE special' at line 2
```

```html
SELECT specials.specials_id, specials.products_id,specials_new_products_price, products.products_image,  products.products_price,products.products_image, products.products_quantity,products.products_model,products_description.products_name,products_description.products_description,
FROM specials 
LEFT JOIN  products_description
LEFT JOIN  products
WHERE specials.products_id = products.products_id AND specials.products_id = products_description.products_id AND products.products_quantity>0
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Example

```
SELECT specials.specials_id, specials.products_id,specials_new_products_price, products.products_image,  products.products_price,products.products_image, products.products_quantity,products.products_model,products_description.products_name,products_description.products_description
FROM specials 
LEFT JOIN  products on specials.products_id = products.products_id
LEFT JOIN  products_description on specials.products_id = products_description.products_id
WHERE products.products_quantity>0
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

wrong comma before FROM

```
SELECT 
      specials.specials_id
    , specials.products_id
    , specials_new_products_price
    , products.products_image
    , products.products_price
    , products.products_image
    , products.products_quantity
    ,products.products_model
    ,products_description.products_name
    ,products_description.products_description
FROM specials 
LEFT JOIN  products_description on specials.products_id = products_description.products_id
LEFT JOIN  products on specials.products_id = products.products_id
WHERE products.products_quantity>0
```